# What is the computational complexity of NSDictionary's -allKeys method?

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdictionary

What is the computational complexity of NSDictionary's -allKeys method?

I would assume it to be O(1) as NSDictionary probably keeps it internally somewhere but you never know :). I tried to look in documentation (NSDictionary and Collections guide) and coundn't find the answer.

Maybe there is some cheat sheet with computational complexities of Cocoa collections' methods?

EDIT:
As was pointed out by Gwendal Roué my question is a bit vague. So I should probably rephrase it like this:

Did someone make measurements of computational complexity of NSDictionary class for some given set of methods and objects and in particular for -allKeys?

EDIT2: 
As was pointed out by Chris Devereux these measurements will be implementation dependent but I think it would be nice if someone could share some tables/measurements just to have some approximate numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Go read this wonderful article that explains how NSArray changes its underlying implementation depending on the number of elements it contains: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html

After that, you'll understand why Apple doesn't document the complexity of its collection classes, including NSDictionary.

Comment: I have already read it. Ok, I see that I have to rephrase my question then.

Comment: Even if somebody did measure the computational complexity of NSDictionary, it's free to change between releases so can't be relied on. If you really need strong guarantees about that sort of thing, it's probably better not to use the Foundation collections.

Comment: @ChrisDevereux I don't need strong guarantees. I would like to have some approximate estimates to have a feeling of what is going on under the hood.

Comment: You should assume -allKeys is O(n). An NSDictionary implementation will have a list of keys, but providing it in NSArray form usually means making a copy of that list.